# Facebook Auto Login to Share

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, authentication, share

I'm currently embedding Facebook Share functionality into my application and wondering if the following is possible:

I have a number of items on the Admin dashboard and I want the ability to Share these items via social media. But as this is on the admin dashboard, instead of the user having to login to share the post I want it to automatically login for them. Is it possible to store the username and password somewhere on my system and use them to auto login when the admin clicks share on their dashboard. The idea would be that it would be a company account and the company would have its own facebook page and so when sharing one of the items they just press share and the company facebook account opens and they can easily share without having to login everytime.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

Comment: No, and you are not even allowed to store actual Facebook user login credentials. Implement this properly, make the post/share via API – then you can use a page access token to share on the page as the page. Extend that page access token, then it will not have any default expiry.